# Fetch localstorage value in array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am saving value in localstorage as shown below

`key` = profskill , `value` = "a,b,c"

In my `test.ts` file, I have declared array but I am unable to fetch the result in it. Code shown below:

```
 getskills: Array<string> = [];
this.getskills  = localStorage.getItem("profskill");
```

but this is giving error:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'string[]'

I want to fetch value like this:

`console.log(this.getskills[0]);`

Comment: value needs to be an array containing 'a','b','c'

Comment: i am saving this way `this.service.profskills_value = this.skills + "," + this.skills2 + "," + this.skills3;`  , please advise how will you save it ?

Comment: `localStorage.setItem( 'profskill', JSON.stringify( ['a', 'b', 'c'] ) )`

Comment: @user2828442 you can tick the answer if if was helpful to you

Answer (score 3):

Since, you want the comma separated value to be represented as a array of strings for `this.getskills` use `split` on the value of the `localStorage`

Here is a sample example

```js
 //say we get the value 'a,b,c' from localStorage into the temp variable
 //var temp = localStorage.getItem(profskill);
  var temp= 'a,b,c';
 
 this.getskills = temp.split(',');
 console.log(this.getskills[0]);
```

Comment: done as you guided, but `console.log(this.getskills[0]);` result is showing `"a,b,c"` ,  i was expecting only `a` , please advise

Comment: But, in this way, the first element will be 'a,b,c', because localStorage must be parsed from JSON first. `this.getskills = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('profskill') );`

Comment: No need to parse in JSON. Check the answer above it works perfectly as asked by OP.

Comment: I see. However, that's not the standard. See Jeremy's answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153340/discussion-between-aka-and-tib).

Comment: This just won't work. `say we get the value 'a,b,c' from localStorage` but you won't. If you try to store `[a,b,c]` in the localStorage, it will be stored as `"[a,b,c]"`. If you split that, it will give you `[ "[a" , "b" , "c]" ]`.

Comment: this is how it worked - `this.getskills  = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("profskill")).split(',');`

Comment: OP has clearly mentioned value = "a,b,c" not value = "[a,b,c]" @JeremyThille

Comment: Oh you're right, my bad. He also said that he was trying to get an array of strings, I got confused.

Comment: Yes, this answer should be accepted as it is exactly what OP wants

Answer (score 3):

The LocalStorage can only store strings, not objects or arrays. If you try to store an array, it will automatically be converted to a string. You need to parse it back to an array :

```
JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem("profskill") )
```

Answer (score 1):

`localStorage` only supports strings. Use `JSON.stringify()` to set the data in storage and `JSON.parse()` to get the data from storage and then use `split(",")` to split the comma separated data.

```js
var obj = "a,b,c";
localStorage.setItem("profskill", JSON.stringify(obj));

var getskills = [];

getskills = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("profskill")).split(",");

console.log(getskills[0]);
```

Comment: It works, but that's not the standard. Take a look at Jeremy's answer

Comment: `console.log(this.getskills[0]);`  is giving me `"a`  , i am expecting only `a`

Comment: I don't think this works. Because an array like `[1,2]` will be stored as `"[1,2]"`. If you just split that, it will give you `[ "[1" , "2]" ]`.

Answer (score 1):

First get the data from the `LocalStorage`:

```
var DataTableValue = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dataTableValue'));
```

Then, store in an Array:

```
var tempArray = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < DTarray.length; i++) {
    tempArray.push(DTarray[i]);
}
```

All data will be stored in the variable `tempArray`.